# ¿Por qué al descomprimir unos ficheros se modifican los permisos?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Os explico mi duda. Como podéis ver en la imagen tengo varios archivos y directorios nombrados como test*. El problema está en el test6 que es un enlace simbólico a test0 (que lo creé con ln -s test0 test6).

En la parte de arriba de la imagen se puede observar que el directorio test6 tiene todos los permisos. Es entonces cuando, con el comando tar -cf exo2.tar * creo el archivo tar conteniendo todos los test. La cuestión es que, después para comprobar, al sacar todos los archivos del .tar el test6 vuelve a tener los permisos modificados.

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo conseguir que se mantengan los permisos después de descomprimir? Porque esto sólo me sucede si lo descomprimo por consola con el comando tar -xf exo2.tar, porque si lo hago por la interfaz gráfica mantiene los permisos.

Gracias.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he utilizado tar -pxf.
Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Se pierden cuando comprimes.

Usa el modificador para preservarlos

```
tar --preserve-permissions --preserve-order -jc /path/to/your/folder > /path/to/your/backup_file.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo. Al final he utilizado tar -pxf y va perfecto. Un saludo.

Comment: @pablo42malaga ponlo como respuesta! Ahí recibes votos positivos e incluso puedes marcarla como aceptada en unas horas :)